# sudoedit_enhanced written POSIX-ly (readlink possible problem?)

Tags: file, posix, sh

## `sudoedit_enhanced` written POSIX-ly challenge

---

While creating `sudoedit_enhanced` POSIX (apart from `readlink` I have been pointed out) shell script snippet, I face two challenges:

1. check if all the files exist, it does not make sense to create a new file this way
2. `sudoedit` does not work with symlinks, so translate symlinks to normal file paths

The core part (*carved out*) checking the existence of files and translates symlinks to normal files follows:

---

```sh
for file in "$@"; do
    if ! [ -f "$file" ]; then
        printf '%s\n' >&2 "sudoedit_enhanced_run(): This file ('$file') does not exist or it is not a regular file."
        return 1
    fi
    [ -L "$file" ] && file=$(readlink -f "$file")
    set -- "$@" "$file"
    shift
done
```

---

It should work, though not much testing has been done so far, I am quite positive there is space to improve.